# Prove that if there exists an ascending chain of subfields of E such that [E_(i):E_(i-1)]=2 for all i if and only if [E:K] is a power of 2.

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, extension-field

Let $F/K$ be a Galois extension, and let $E$ be an intermediate field; $E$ is said to be a **$2$-tower** over $K$ if there exists an ascending chain of subfields between $K$ and $E$ such that $[E_i:E_{i-1}]=2$ for all $i$. Suppose that $Aut(E:K$) is abelian. Prove that $E$ is a **$2$-tower** over $K$ if and only if $[E:K]$ is a power of $2$.

Comment: What theorems do you have available? This follows immediately from a well-known fact that $[E:K]=[E:F][F:K]$ for an intermediate field $F$.

Comment: So you mean if we apply this known result on the  chain, then we are done?

Comment: Assuming $E$ is a $2$-tower over $K$, then $[E:K]$ is a power of $2$ using the above statement. The converse makes use of the hypothesis that $Aut(E:K)$ is abelian.

Comment: I am still nit sure where to use the abelian part. We have such similar theorem in group theory which is called a composition series of subgroups. Is it related to what we are solving here?